# spinnaker deploy failed :installation issue Local Debian Deployment

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

Spinnaker installation failed:

A Spinnaker installation in AWS EC2 is failing. The selected choice is local debian. Halyard cannot complete the deployment and shows an error in execution

Environment:
AWS EC2
storage: S3
Deployment Type: Local debian /GIT

What could be the reason of this failure on my deployment?

hal version:  1.10.1-20180912131447
spinnaker version :  1.9.4

`hal deploy apply` : Failed with below error

```
/opt/halyard/bin/hal: 22: /etc/default/spinnaker: [[: not found
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx8G
+ Get current deployment
  Success
+ Prep deployment
  Success
Problems in default.provider.aws.spin-install:
- WARNING No validation for the AWS provider has been
  implemented.
+ Preparation complete... deploying Spinnaker
~/dev/spinnaker/clouddriver ~/dev/spinnaker ~
git@github.com:spinnaker/clouddriver.git
No changes to stash in clouddriver
HEAD is now at 41f14e1... fix(config): Move core config to clouddriver.config package (#2994)
~/dev/spinnaker/deck ~/dev/spinnaker ~
git@github.com:spinnaker/deck.git
No changes to stash in deck
HEAD is now at f208cbf... fix(core): Fix error when changing execution grouping (#5793)
~/dev/spinnaker/echo ~/dev/spinnaker ~
git@github.com:spinnaker/echo.git
No changes to stash in echo
HEAD is now at b20d3d0... chore(pubsub): add a global enable flag for pubsub (#345)
~/dev/spinnaker/fiat ~/dev/spinnaker ~
git@github.com:spinnaker/fiat.git
No changes to stash in fiat
HEAD is now at 4045c08... chore(dependencies): Bump spinnaker dependencies to 1.0.13 (#262)
~/dev/spinnaker/front50 ~/dev/spinnaker ~
git@github.com:spinnaker/front50.git
No changes to stash in front50
HEAD is now at f7f83f8... refactor(gcs): Update doRetry and bump clouddriver version (#355)
~/dev/spinnaker/gate ~/dev/spinnaker ~
git@github.com:spinnaker/gate.git
No changes to stash in gate
HEAD is now at 47440fb... chore(dependencies): Update gradle plugin to 4.3.0 (#602)
~/dev/spinnaker/igor ~/dev/spinnaker ~
git@github.com:spinnaker/igor.git
No changes to stash in igor
HEAD is now at 2a3d239... chore(dependencies): Bump spinnaker dependencies to 1.0.13 (#303)
~/dev/spinnaker/kayenta ~/dev/spinnaker ~
git@github.com:spinnaker/kayenta.git
No changes to stash in kayenta
HEAD is now at c423808... fix(stackdriver): Drop project_id from response tags. (#382)
~/dev/spinnaker/orca ~/dev/spinnaker ~
git@github.com:spinnaker/orca.git
No changes to stash in orca
HEAD is now at e57fbce... feat(queue): Add `stageType` and `taskType` to MDC while task executing (#2428)
~/dev/spinnaker ~
~/dev/spinnaker ~
~/dev/spinnaker/rosco ~/dev/spinnaker ~
git@github.com:spinnaker/rosco.git
No changes to stash in rosco
HEAD is now at f785bf2... fix(bake/oracle): scrape image id as well as name. (#278)
~/dev/spinnaker ~
+ Get current deployment
  Success
- Apply deployment
  Failure
Problems in Global:
! ERROR Unexpected exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
  Index: 0, Size: 0
- Failed to deploy Spinnaker.
```

Comment: "ERROR Unexpected exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0" - can you track down the code that that's coming from, e.g. is there a full stacktrace anywhere or can you modify the script so that it shows you one, and and work out what's expected to be in the array that isn't?

Comment: Found solution: 
Issue with halyard version..I have tried with hal v 1.8.0 and java exception error is no more occurring

Answer (score 0):

Local Debian option should only be used for plugin and Spinnaker development. 
If you require a deployment installation use Kubernetes or get started by using Minnaker.

For that issue I suggest:

- Upgrade [Halyard](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/halyard/)
- Make sure your config is appropriate by running `hal config`
- Install with `hal config deploy edit --type localdebian`
- Deploy by running `hal deploy apply`